# Swift Bounds unavailable

Tags: xcode, swift, bounds, cgpoint

When I build the app the error points to the code below and says ***'bounds' is unavailable***. The code had previously worked but now it causes the build to fail.

```
let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionView)

let cellIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInTable)
println(cellIndexPath)
```

Comment: how is `sender` defined?

Comment: The sender is a UIButton in a collection view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` *is* a UIButton, perhaps, but Swift doesn't *know* that. It knows only what you tell it. You have to tell it, so that Swift knows that this is a thing that has a `bounds` property. The easiest way is to cast:

```
let button = sender as UIButton
let pointInTable: CGPoint = button.convertPoint(button.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionView)
```

Also, are you sure that `self.collectionView` is not an Optional? In some versions of Xcode/Swift, it is, and you would have to unwrap it (`self.collectionView!`).